# Ag grid: How to add a row with sorting order

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have been trying an issue like while adding the row into ag grid, it is always adding in bottom of the grid without sort order.

I would like to add the row with sorting order here the example what is happening when I add the row,

**Actual results is**

```
4
5
6
1 => Newly added row without sorting.
```

**Expected result is**

```
1 => Newly added row with sorting.
4
5
6
```

This is the syntax using from Ag-grid.

```
const addedRow = this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: [view.data]});
      addedRow.add[0].setSelected(true);
```

Any expert advice

**No sort(Default: Loading the data as per the array order)**

8

4

9

1 => Added new Row

**Ascending**

1 => Added new Row

4

8

9

**Descending**

9

8

4

1 => Added new Row

Comment: Have you add an order condition on your ag-grid ?

Answer (score 8):

You can set the sort order of your grid using the `gridApi`.

In the `onGridReady` callback, set the following sort:

```
onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;

      var sort = [
          {
            colId: "id",
            sort: "asc"
          }
        ];
        this.gridApi.setSortModel(sort);
    }
```

Then when you've added your new row, it will be automatically order by the `id` field in ascending order.

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-gv2t6i) StackBlitz example.

Comment: Thank you. It is working great with "asc" but It is not working with default sort mode Can we doable for default mode while add the new row?

Comment: What do you mean by "default sort mode"?

Comment: no sort mode called default like 1. Default(no sort) 2.Asc 3.Desc.

Comment: There is no "default" sort mode in ag-grid. Take a look at the documentation on sorting [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/)

Comment: Updated the post about default order. Please check.

Comment: You'll want to set the sort to "". Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-hftmby) updated StackBlitz to see this in action.